# How to retrieve the most recent modified (activity)time and the ResourceName(Id) of an AzResource that has been active for the last 90 days PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, activitylog

In order to cutoff the cost. I need to deprecate or move those resources that have not been in use for the last 90 days. How to automate this task in PowerShell?

With the help of `Get-AzureRmLog` I got all the resource logs and the timestamps.

Now I need to filter the most recent change date and their status.

If the status is Active, I need to shortlist (remove) separately, else the same. I need to automate this task every 15 days.

If anyone knows the script, please help. **Priority**

Comment: What code have you written so far? What worked, and what didn’t work?  This site works best when you ask a specific technical question about an error or behaviour in existing code, rather than a generic request for help - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

Get-AzActivityLog cmdlet has EventTimeStamp parameter so using where-object cmdlet pull all logs that are since 90 days and then get list of resources using ResourceId parameter. Use Get-AzResource and then get list of resources. Now, compare the difference of resources.